# How to use sound files through all controllers in Swift 3

Tags: swift, audio

I've some simple sounds and I have multiple View Controllers and I wonder how to use sounds in every controller in my app. Should I create an extension, protocol, struct or something else? What would be the best OOP approach? There are plenty of tutorials but none of them shows how to efficiently use sounds in your app.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for but see [Protocol and Value Oriented Programming in UIKit Apps - WWDC 2016 - Session 419](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/419/) basically you wrap your audio file in a struct, then use protocols and extensions and possibly generics.

Comment: Thanks. Will watch it!

Answer (score 1):

With your context, I suggest you to write something like SoundService, and declare it as a singleton. So every controller has the access to this service. The parameter for the service is something like sound file names.

This service will be used in the app, anytime the controller wants to play a sound, just call a method in the singleton. That will make your code looks better, and if you find any problem related to Sound, you know where to find the problem.